# CAKeyframeAnimation with bezier curves and constant velocity

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation

I'm attempting to animate a graphic along a `CGPathRef` that contains some bezier curves, and I'd like the animation to have a smooth, constant velocity from beginning to ending. What I'm running into though is that the animation is easing in and out every time it hits a key point. I've tried using different `timingFunction` and `calculationMode` settings but I can't seem to find the right combination to get the job done.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
-(void)animate
{
  CAKeyframeAnimation *posAnim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
  posAnim.path = [self pathForAnimation];
  posAnim.duration = 12.0;
  posAnim.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
  posAnim.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
  posAnim.removedOnCompletion = NO;
  posAnim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
  [image.layer addAnimation:posAnim forKey:@"posAnim"];
}

-(CGPathRef)pathForAnimation
{
  CGMutablePathRef path;
  CGPoint point;
  CGPoint controlPoint1;
  CGPoint controlPoint2;

  path = CGPathCreateMutable();
  point = CGPointMake(209.5f, 24.5f);
  CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, point.x, point.y);

  point = CGPointMake(249.5f, 64.5f);
  controlPoint1 = CGPointMake(232.5f, 25.5f);
  controlPoint2 = CGPointMake(249.5f, 37.5f);
  CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, NULL, controlPoint1.x, controlPoint1.y, controlPoint2.x, controlPoint2.y, point.x, point.y);

  point = CGPointMake(146.5f, 301.5f);
  controlPoint1 = CGPointMake(249.5f, 91.5f);
  controlPoint2 = CGPointMake(147.5f, 258.5f);
  CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, NULL, controlPoint1.x, controlPoint1.y, controlPoint2.x, controlPoint2.y, point.x, point.y);

  point = CGPointMake(146.5f, 458.5f);
  controlPoint1 = CGPointMake(145.5f, 344.5f);
  controlPoint2 = CGPointMake(170.5f, 418.5f);
  CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, NULL, controlPoint1.x, controlPoint1.y, controlPoint2.x, controlPoint2.y, point.x, point.y);

  point = CGPointMake(18.5f, 530.5f);
  controlPoint1 = CGPointMake(122.5f, 498.5f);
  controlPoint2 = CGPointMake(18.5f, 530.5f);
  CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, NULL, controlPoint1.x, controlPoint1.y, controlPoint2.x, controlPoint2.y, point.x, point.y);

  return path;
}
```

For what its worth, I've tried replacing the curves with straight lines (using `CGPathAddLineToPoint`) and that gives me a constant velocity like I want. But of course I'd rather have the curves if possible.

I've also tried replacing `timingFunction` with a `timingFunctions` array, to no avail.

Comment: You're showing the wrong part of your code - could you show the part where you actually create the animation? For example I'd like to see how you're supplying the calculation mode and whether you're using a paced animation. Remember, as we round a curve, distance to travel increases, so even with linear timing function we will appear to slow on the curves, and the calculation must thus be told to try to compensate for that. If that doesn't work, you might have to specify some key points and times explicitly.

Comment: Isn't that the part under my `-(void)animate` function? Its there at the top. I do agree with you though, there is something in that block of code that I'm not doing right.

Comment: oops didn't see that part of the code!

Comment: Ok, and is kCAAnimationCubicPaced no better? If not, you may have to play with the biasValues etc. As I say, the curve itself implicitly involves an appearance of slowing even with a linear timing. Alternatively, create your own timing function where you speed up at the extremes, to overcome the apparent slowing.

Comment: Yeah, the `kCAAnimationCubicPaced` mode looked fairly similar. I'll see what I can do with biasValues and/or a custom timing function.

Answer (score 3):

You did try setting the keyframe animation's calculationMode property to kCAAnimationCubicPaced? That property is specifically for making the animation follow a constant pace for the whole curve.

Comment: Yep, tried that. Didn't seem to make a difference at the time. I ended up dropping the bezier curves entirely and settling on direct lines from point to point.